# Div Height doesnt get resized after AJAX call completion

Tags: ajax, html, resize

I wanted to increase the height of my div (id = scroller) and set it at the end of the success call back function. In the success callback function I dynamically inject some inner div's which are contained in the "scroller" div.

Default height of scroller div is 400 px. Dynamically it comes e.g. as 900px, then it  should be set as 900px.

```
height = $('#content').innerHeight();     
alert("outside: " + height);   
$('#scroller').css('height', height + "px");
```

So far so good. Now, this resizing works if I have an alert statement. If I remove the alert, it doesnt resize itself.

What might be the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. height: auto doesnt work maybe because I am expecting this functionality on android emulator/cellphone and i am developing my mobile app using Phonegap.

Comment: Can you post also a bit of your html ?

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="scroller">
           <div id="content" class="ui-body ui-body-a" style="margin:0px;">
            <div id="disp_content">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>

Comment: Can you try _$('#scroller').height(height);_

Comment: I solved the probem yesterday only... Sorry I couldnt post it immediately..Here's the solution, I used iScroll.refresh() after resizing the div height since iScroll didnt detect the DOM changes after div height had been changed. So, you need to call iScroll.refresh() for it to adjust its scrollbar size according to changed DIV size.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a new div, loading your data into it, then using the jQuery replaceWith() method to replace the old content div with the new one. That might be one way to force the browser to recalculate the height of the (new) content div and everything around it.
Something like:

```
var newContent = $('<div id="content"></div>').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
$('#content').replaceWith(newContent);
```